# What's the position of the tongue when speaking 'l' at the end of a word?

Tags: preposiciones

I want to know where I should put my tongue at last when speak words like 'fidel', 'mundial','al'' international'. the position of tip of my tongue should be on the upper teeth, or gum ridge  or between the upper teeth and lower teeth?

Answer (score 6):

### The tongue tip should be pressed against the gum ridge and placed behind the upper front teeth like in the figure.

[image]

Comment: With some regional variation... When I say it, (I speak ríoplatense Spanish) the tip of the tongue is a bit further back, against the back side of the alveolar ridge (hence, aslo a bit higher). If I pronounce it the way the picture indicates... I feel I soud more Caribean...